# Entity framework: How to map Int64 field to Int32 db column?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

There is an `int` ID column in a MS SQL database table, but the entity class contains a `long` ID field, and I get the following message in the context:

> "An exception occured while reading a database value. The expected
>   type was 'System.Int64' but the actual value was of type
>   'System.Int32'."

I've already tried to set the column type:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<XXXEntity>()
            .Property(b => b.Id)
            .HasColumnName("XXXId")
            .HasColumnType("int");
```

but that does not work.
What's the right solution?

I cannot change neither the entity class nor the db table.

Comment: change the long id field to int?

Comment: I cannot change it

Comment: force it to be int by using `Convert.ToInt32(myLongIdField)`. But there is valid reason why the program doesn't allow you to insert long into int type column. use this only if you are very sure that your "long" data will not be too big.

Comment: I do not want to insert data, I just want to read it

Answer (score 2):

You should map `Int64` into `bigint` on SQL server:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<XXXEntity>()
            .Property(b => b.Id)
            .HasColumnName("XXXId")
            .HasColumnType("bigint");
```

**UPDATE:**
Since your SQL column data type is `int`, you should change your `Id` datatype inside `XXXEntity` class to `Int32`

Comment: Thanks, but the same result.

Comment: @Aaaaaaaa what is the **actual** type of `XXXId` column on SQL Server?

Comment: int, as I wrote

Comment: Then your Entity Class `XXXEntity` must have `Int32` (i.e. int) data type, not `Int64` (i.e. long). Try to ask yourself how would you put 8 bytes into 4 bytes - it's not possible :)

Comment: I cannot change neither the entity class nor the db table. And I use the db just as read only

Comment: @Aaaaaaaa Why not? Isn't `XXXEntity` class under your control?

Comment: Yes, it is, but I have to use it with legacy db too.

Comment: @Aaaaaaaa then you should have two different `Id` properties. One for legacy db (e.g. `LegacyId` which corresponds to datatype inside legacy db) and one for new db (e.g. `Id` which corresponds to datatype of new db)

Comment: If there is no other solution, than I schould have two IDs, yes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not tested. But can try?

```
public long id { get { return id; } set { id.GetType() == typeof(Int64) ? id : Convert.ToInt64(id); }}
```